# Including the standalone script is not working

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am simply including the script `dropzone.js`.

When doing this:

```
var dropZone = new Dropzone(..., {
  url: '...'
});
```

I get the following javascript error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined
```

I have also requirejs coming from the platform we're running automatically but I don't want to use that. Could that have anything to do with it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable RequireJS for a single file by setting `define.amd` to false:

```
<script>
    window.oldDefineAmd = define.amd;
    define.amd = false;
</script>
<script src="dropzone.js"></script>
<script>define.amd = window.oldDefineAmd;</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pxp5L/5/

But note that this can break all kinds of stuff.

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of alot of stuff I didn't get. Now I get a new error though: `Uncaught Error: Module name "emitter" has not been loaded yet for context: _`

Comment: Yep, that doesn't work because the file depends on component's Emitter. Using the regular file with the above code however does work, tested it this time. :)

Comment: That's just because GitHub does not set the correct content type: http://jsfiddle.net/Pxp5L/5/